# Problem with JavaScript (JQuery) while working on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I am creating a drawing tool using HTML, CSS and JavaScript(JQuery) on canvas.

In desktop, it starts drawing when I click on the canvas and continues to draw even if I released the click and move the mouse ( I want it to draw only when I am holding the click and moving the mouse).

When it comes to mobile, it starts drawing after 2 touches (I don't know why) and draws as expected i.e. only when I am holding it. But here the problem is, when I touch somewhere else, instead of drawing a dot where I touched, it draws a line from where I stopped previously till the current location( for example, if I stopped at bottom-left of page previously and again touch at top-right of the page to start, it draws a line across).

I've added a lot of stuff (relevant or not I don't know) by looking at other answers but it doesn't work. Please help me out with these 2 problems. Thank you.

Here's the JS code after removing the part which I know is not causing problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let color = "black";
    let x;
    let y;
    let isPressed;

    const canvas = $("canvas");
    const colorElement = $("#color");
    const ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    const canvass = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    let prevX,prevY;

    canvas.on("mousedown",(e)=>{
        isPressed = true;
        prevX = x;
        prevY = y;
        x = e.pageX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        y = e.pageY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    });
    $("document").on("mouseup",(e)=>{
        isPressed = false;
        x = undefined;
        y = undefined;
    });
    canvas.on("mousemove",(e)=>{
        if(isPressed){
            e.preventDefault();    /*added this after looking at other answers*/
            e.stopPropagation();   /*added this after looking at other answers*/
            x = e.pageX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
            y = e.pageY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
            drawCircle(x,y);
            drawLine(prevX,prevY,x,y);
            prevX = x;
            prevY = y;
        }
    });
    
    /*for the app to work on mobile devices*/
    canvass.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
        canvass.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
    }, false);
    canvass.addEventListener("touchdown", function (e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
        canvass.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
    }, false);
    canvass.addEventListener("touchup", function (e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
        canvass.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
    }, false);
    
    function drawCircle(x,y){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,size,0,Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function drawLine(x,y,x2,y2){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth = size*2;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    colorElement.on("change",(e)=>{
        color = e.target.value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the touch problem you have to use touchstart instead of touchdown.
More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp

The mouse problem seems to be due to the event listener being linked to `$("document")` instead of `canvas` like the other ones. Probably the mousemove event fires before the mouseup event and prevents bubbling up with `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`
Try deleting these lines and/or linking the mouseup event to canvas itself.

Comment: I changed `$("document")` to `canvas` and it solved the desktop problem but the tool stopped working for mobile. After changing "touchdown" to "touchstart", it started to work but I am still facing the same problem for mobile but a bit different (if i just put two dots, it doesn't connect them, but if I draw 2 lines, it connects them)... So, the status is that desktop's problem has been solved but mobile's issue is still prevalent...